# TypeError: Cannot read property 'measure' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I have a problem with measure in react native :

```
checkPositionComponant = (id) => {
    this.refs.component.measure((a, b, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
      tabTag[id].positionY = pageY;
     });
  }

  componentTag() {
   return tabTag.map((item, id) => {
      return(
        <View key={id} style={styles.componentView} ref="component">
          { this.checkPositionComponant(id) }
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
```

And my error is : TypeError: Cannot read property 'measure' of undefined

Comment: So that means `this.refs.component` is undefined

Comment: Is it being rendered?

Comment: what did you mean by Is it being rendered ? componentTag is called in my render methode like that <View> { this.componentTag() } </View>

Answer (score 4):

1. You're using the same ref on multiple components
2. From [react docs](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html):

> Never access refs inside of any component's render method – or while any component's render method is even running anywhere in the call stack.

You might want to align your code with react's lifecycle and use

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.checkPositionComponant(id);
}
```

Where `checkPositionComponant` should change the state (setState / dispatch) in order for the components to re-render.

Have a look at [this example](http://www.react.express/refs_and_the_dom).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.
This works fine in ios but for android, it returns undefined unless
you put empty callback on the **onLayout** property.
You can do this in your view component:-

```
<View key={id} style={styles.componentView} ref="component" onLayout={() => {}}>
     { this.checkPositionComponant(id) }
</View>
```

If you want to read more, [you can read this issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3282)